# Condition pandas data Frame

Tags: pandas

columuns in my data are [Instrument,Account Number,Trade PnL]

How can i find the number of unique account number given with condition that Instrument =='AAPL'

```
    df[['Account Number'](df['Instrument'] == 'AAPL'].nunique()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be:

```
df['Account Number'][df['Instrument'] == 'AAPL'].nunique()
```